# "Function Types", What's the difference and why are they useful?

Tags: typescript, typescript2.4

In the TS docs over at: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/functions.html, "Function Types" are introduced. The code for such an example is:

```
let myAdd: (x: number, y: number) => number =
    function(x: number, y: number): number { return x+y; };
```

Where as for the "non-typed" function it is

```
let myAdd = function(x: number, y: number): number { return x+y; };
```

To me, the extra syntax in the first example is very strange. Why is there arrow-function syntax for the return type? Why are there two parameter specifications?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typing the function is useful if you don't know what the function will be when the variable is declared:

```
let myOperation: (x: number, y: number) => number;

if ( // some condition ) {
  myOperation = function (x: number, y: number): number { return x + y; };
} else {
  myOperation = function (x: number, y: number): number { return x * y; }
}
```

Note that in some places (e.g. interfaces) you can describe the type with or without the arrow:

```
interface WithoutArrow {
  operation(x: number, y: number): number;
}

interface WithArrow {
  operation: (x: number, y: number) => number;
}
```

Comment: And that would be the only reasonable use-case?

Comment: @user7722867 there are other places where you may need to type a function (like to create a typed method in an interface, or a typed parameter to a function which is itself a function, etc.). In some places you just don't need the arrow to describe the type, like in an interface. I updated my answer.

Comment: This answer is generally good, but note that the arrow makes a fairly big semantic difference

Comment: @AluanHaddad In an interface definition, what would be the difference?

Comment: @FrankModica it depends on if the interface is implemented using a class or an object. If you use an object then it makes little difference, but if you use a class, something I would generally advise against but seems to be wildly popular these days, then it does make a big difference because it affects the shape of the Prototype, assuming you implement the interface correctly.

Comment: @AluanHaddad If I understand correctly, you interpret the method in the interface as implying whether an implementation should be an arrow function or not? I never really saw it that way since I assumed interfaces were there just to define signatures and not anything about how they're implemented, so I assumed TypeScript was just providing us multiple ways to write a method signature. Interesting point though, since as you mentioned an arrow function in a class would not end up on a prototype.